# How to verify JSON request and response in Java?

Tags: java, json, rest, selenium, automation

I have created selenium data driven frame work to register new users. I'll be creating the new user registration via UI, using selenium code. Once the user registration is complete, I access the REST API url, API request, and I need to verify the response.

How can I verify this? I have the API URL, REST API request and REST API response.

Please guide me.  I'm using Java as a programming language.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Could you add information regarding what you have tried already, and what problems you are running into?

Comment: Don't use Selenium. Pick *any* of the Java REST libraries instead.

Comment: @SiKing Are you saying as we need to add Java rest libraries in our buildpath?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python, use requests for GET or POST or whatever you need.
Below is the example you can follow :

```
    def get_Request(self, resourceURI):
        url = baseURL + resourceURI
        headers = “header value"
        r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        print r.status_code
        print r.text
```

that will give you status code and text which you can compare as you would like

For POST

```
    def post_Request(self, resourceURI, payload):
        url = baseURL + resourceURI
        headers = “Headers here"
        r = requests.post(url,'data',json,headers=headers)
```

Don’t forget to import requests

Here is your guide for requests

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

If you are using java , follow this :

http://unirest.io/java.html